# Migrate Single Amazon EBS volumes from gp2 to gp3 with AWS CLI

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-ebs

How can I modify one of the existing volumes from gp2 to gp3 using AWS CLI?

I'd like to try with the script,

```bash
#! /bin/bash

region='us-east-1'

# Find all gp2 volumes within the given region
volume_ids=$(/usr/bin/aws ec2 describe-volumes --region "${region}" --filters Name=volume-type,Values=gp2 | jq -r '.Volumes[].VolumeId')

# Iterate all gp2 volumes and change its type to gp3
for volume_id in ${volume_ids};do
    result=$(/usr/bin/aws ec2 modify-volume --region "${region}" --volume-type=gp3 --volume-id "${volume_id}" | jq '.VolumeModification.ModificationState' | sed 's/"//g')
    if [ $? -eq 0 ] && [ "${result}" == "modifying" ];then
        echo "OK: volume ${volume_id} changed to state 'modifying'"
    else
        echo "ERROR: couldn't change volume ${volume_id} type to gp3!"
    fi
done
```

To verify script works as we'd expect but only one 1 machine rather than all using gp2? What changes do i need to done with the script?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a break in your loop after entring the conditions to stop in the first element if you want to test in speed mode :)

like :

```
# Iterate all gp2 volumes and change its type to gp3
for volume_id in ${volume_ids};do
    result=$(/usr/bin/aws ec2 modify-volume --region "${region}" --volume-type=gp3 --volume-id "${volume_id}" | jq '.VolumeModification.ModificationState' | sed 's/"//g')
    if [ $? -eq 0 ] && [ "${result}" == "modifying" ];then
        echo "OK: volume ${volume_id} changed to state 'modifying'"
        break  <==== 
    else
        echo "ERROR: couldn't change volume ${volume_id} type to gp3!"
    fi
done
```

But I recommand to you to be more specific on your first request, get specific Volume by addind Tag filter (Name), to get only one volume EBS for testing purpose

Comment: Thanks Hatim , can this work if i add --filters Name=attachment.instance-id,Values=i-1234567890abcdef0 to aws ec2 describe-volumes command within the script. We also can select specific volumes with --volume-ids vol-049df61146c4d7901 vol-1234567890abcdef0

Comment: You can do it,  or use tags by adding a tag on the volume or the instance   like (TEST: yes) and on your describe you can add a filter like this 
--filters 'Name=tag:'TEST',Values=*'

Answer (score 0):

For an ebs volume type modification from aws console or cli. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/requesting-ebs-volume-modifications.html

Alternatively, using AWS Systems Manager > Automation > Execute.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager-automation-runbooks/latest/userguide/automation-aws-modify-ebs-type.html

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post link-only answers but summarize the linked content or its relevant parts a little. A link may become invalid or outdated and in that case, your answer would be useless in the future.